# setting up ssh passwordless in ec2 via chef

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I have the following `recipe/default.rb` in Chef:

```
# Create empty RSA password
template "#{node[:cluster][:ubuntu]}/my_key.pem" do
   source "keys.pem.erb"
   mode 0400
   owner "ubuntu"
   group "ubuntu"
end

bash "ssh-passwordless" do
   user "ubuntu"
   cwd "#{node[:cluster][:ubuntu]}"
   code <<-EOF
   eval `ssh-agent -s`
   ssh-add #{node[:cluster][:ubuntu]}/my_key.pem
   EOF
end

# Create empty RSA password
execute "ssh-keygen" do
  command "sudo -u ubuntu ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
  creates "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
 action :run
end

# Copy public key to node1; if key doesn't exist in authorized_keys, append it to this file
execute <<EOF
cat /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sudo -u ubuntu ssh ubuntu@localhost "(cat > /tmp/tmp.pubkey; mkdir -p .ssh; touch .ssh/authorized_keys; grep #{node[:fqdn]} .ssh/authorized_keys > /dev/null || cat /tmp/tmp.pubkey >> .ssh/authorized_keys; rm /tmp/tmp.pubkey)
```

As you can see, I'm trying a lot of methods to get it to work, however, none of them have succeed so far. The goal is to remove the need of password / pem file in EC2, so I can set up a hadoop cluster. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to create a private key on node1 to be able to connect on node2 via ssh.

You can do it quite easily with search .

On node1:

```
# Create empty RSA password
execute "ssh-keygen" do
  command "sudo -u ubuntu ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
  creates "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
end

ruby_block "expose public key in attribute" do
  block do
    node.default['public_key'] = ::File.read("/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  end
end
```

On node2, search for node1's public key:

```
node1 = search(:node, "name:node1").first
file '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys' do
  content node1['public_key']
end
```

Of course you'll need to adapt this if you need to allow several hosts to connect.